# What is this puzzle?

Tags: logical-deduction, word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, grid-deduction

---

[image]

---

$$\huge\text{This puzzle is _______}$$

Comment: This puzzle is [_______](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114344/what-is-this-puzzle)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It looks to me like this puzzle is:

> **FLOWING!**

Why? First note that:

> There are two dots of each colour in every grid. Each pair can be joined by a continuous line of cells in a way that ensures every cell in the grid is shaded (much like a game of [Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_Free)).
>
>  Their solutions are as follows:
>
>  [image: Solved Flow grids]

Next, there seems to be some sort of hint to the right of the vertical dividing line in the image...

> [From OP] ...the symbols on the right indicate three things - the "no eye" icon indicates [Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille), the eyedropper indicates colour values, and the plus sign shows the colours are added together. Taking the RGB values of the dots in the grid and adding them together in certain ways will give the RGB value of the colour in the Braille grid.
>
>  So for instance, the bottom left colour is RGB(160,143,116) which is made by adding red, orange, green, blue and violet. Finding the combinations for all 6 cells and looking at them in ROYGBIV order gives the Braille for **OVERLAY**.
>
>  [image: Understanding the Braille clue]

We can then...

> ... use this to overlay the grids, by examining the cells occupied by each colour, across all the grids combined. The results form shapes in which the unshaded squares form recognisable letters of the alphabet (or an exclamation mark in the case of white - see below). If we take them in rainbow order (ROYGBIV) with white at the end, we spell out the word **FLOWING!** - an appropriately descriptive word given the name of the game it resembles!
>
>  [image: Letters formed by unshaded squares of each colour]

Comment: Should have known better than to think people would need a hint, correct of course :P The hint (sort of instruction?) may actually be harder to find than the answer itself, will be impressed if you can get that too! If not, I can give it away as the actual answer has been found. Great job, you're too quick with it!!

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Haha, thanks :) You know what, I only actually realised I hadn't explained the hint on the right once I'd posted! Had proper tunnel vision once I spotted what the solution path should be... I've been thinking about it since but don't quite have it yet - I mean, clearly it involves rot13(vagrecergvat gur fvk qbgf nf Oenvyyr fbzrubj - gur oyvaq rlr - naq vg frrzf gur pbybhef va gur Oenvyyr frpgvba ner n pbzovangvba bs bgure pbybhef. Zl fhfcvpvba vf gung gur yrggref bs n jbeq yvxr ENVAOBJ be EBLTOVI unir orra rapbqrq va Oenvyyr naq gurve pbybhe pbqrf nqqrq gbtrgure fbzrubj...)

Comment: I was debating whether or not the puzzle needed an 'instruction' for the final step, clearly overestimated the difficulty. You're pretty much bang on!  I don't want it to be an annoying final part, so I'll leave you with [this link](https://colordesigner.io/color-mixer) and the hint that the last symbol is an eyedropper :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Well, I've used the eyedropper and gone over the palette pretty thoroughly and only managed to create one exact match (the easy one - top right is purely violet!). The hint seems to be pretty difficult to reverse engineer...

Comment: rot13("Npebff nyy gur tevqf pbzovarq" vf irel fzneg naq arire V guvax vg jvyy bpphe gb zr ...)

Comment: @Stiv I can see now that this is way too difficult as a hint, might be easier if I simply add the explanation to your answer? Don’t want to waste your time considering you have already solved the actual puzzle :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Feel free - not convinced I'm going to be able to crack that part without considerable time and/or resources!

Comment: Added, the hint concept was a nice idea but certainly not very practical looking back, wasn't needed at all. Great job with the rest though, heres your tick!

Comment: Thanks @BeastlyGerbil I had the same RGB values as you, but using the defaults provided with the tool you linked to didn't produce the same colours for me. Should have twigged that the colours there were not necessarily the ones you'd used in the puzzle... Ah well. Thanks for the puzzle :)